# Стиль для всех тегов

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. В моём приложение большое количество тегов `<h:outputText>` и во всех надо изменить цвет на белый. Как это сделать? style везде писать не вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Один раз сделай:

```
.my_style {
background-color: цвет
}
```

И вставляй его где нужно!
    <тег class="my_style" ></тег>
    Если в разных страничках, то создай отдельную таблицу стилей файл.css

Answer (score 1):

В CSS можно любому тэгу дать свой стиль, например

```
h1 {
  color: white
}
```

присвоит всем элементам с тэгом `h1` белый цвет текста.

Comment: Так действительно лучше!